# Automate Ubuntu install with WDS

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation

How to write Grub to deploy Ubuntu 12.04 desktop.

I have a working WDS with the ability to install Windows images as well as Centos\Fedora\and GParted without fail. Even has a nice Grub with Sub menus.  I cannot get Ubuntu 12 or higher to boot.

This is what I have in place right now.

```
LABEL UBUNTU
 MENU LABEL Ubuntu Desktop 12.04.3
 KERNEL /LINUX/ubuntu-12.04.3-desktop-i386/casper/vmlinuz
 append boot=casper netboot=nfs nfsroot=10.1.1.77:/LINUX/ubuntu-12.04.3-desktop-i386/ initrd=/LINUX/ubuntu-12.04.3-desktop-i386/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash
```

It will begin the process but then fail saying:

```
(initramfs) unable to find a live file system on the network
```

I can give more info if needed

Comment: You might find this useful: https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/NetbootFirmware

Comment: The output of `sudo lshw -c network` would also be helpful